# Visual Studio .NET: warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions

Tags: .net, visual-studio

The error message is:

> warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference
>   conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
>   detailed.

This has to be one of the most irritating error messages since for some reason they decided (there is a thread about this) to not change how this error is handled, forcing users to go hunt for the problem.

I get many like this:

> Encountered conflict between 'Reference:C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.appcontext\4.3.0\ref\net463\System.AppContext.dll'
>   and 'Reference:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.AppContext.dll'.
>   Choosing 'Reference:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.AppContext.dll'
>   because AssemblyVersion '4.1.2.0' is greater than '4.1.1.0'.

First, the error with old assemblies that were in users/administrator/.nuget/packages.
I removed that folder.

Now it goes to find old assemblies in \program files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder

The whole project is using .NET 4.7

Has anyone see that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution option "restore Nuget packages" didn't work very well.

To cut a long story short, I had to run the NuGet command `Update-Package -reinstall` and then consolodate the different versions across the solution.

I had some problems obtaining detailed debug from the output due to Resharper build, which I had to disable too. I wrote a more detailed article about it [here](https://www.dombat.co.uk/msb3277-conflicts-resolved/) .

Comment: I usually consolidate the versions, wipe all the redirects and rebuild from scratch. Did you conclude that Resharper was one of the problems? it doesn't seem so from your article

Comment: Resharper was only a problem when I was attempting to get the diagnostic output. I could only get it when I disabled resharper build temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify any hardcoded assembly references in your (app/web).config files.
Remove those and use dotnet/nuget to restore your packages using a single packages.config file.