# Getting "Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions" during a build

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I maintain a ASP.NET WebForms app written by someone else who long since left. Even though the app has about 10 .aspx pages in it, the solution has 12 VB.NET projects. All of the warnings in the build are of this type:

> Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.

I've looked here on SO for help. I came across this post [Visual Studio .NET: warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245773/visual-studio-net-warning-msb3277-found-conflicts-between-different-versions). However, the answers given referenced NuGet packages. The conflict in this app I maintain is due to one of the 11 other projects within the Visual Studio solution, so I don't believe the answer I found here on SO, applies in this situation.

At first, I thought all I'd have to do was delete the DLLs being created the web application's `bin` folder. (Not sure why the original developer included the `bin` folder in the project, but he did.) So, I deleted the DLLs and PDB files, but whenever I build the app, it puts them back into the web application's `bin` folder. Perhaps that is the way VB.NET (or .NET) works, it just surprises me. Note: the application does build and can be deployed. I've done so. I'd like to get rid of these warnings.

The original developer wrote this using .NET 2. I upgraded it to .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: The idea is that you're supposed to be able to deploy the web app from that bin folder, so it contains all the libraries that the application requires. Perhaps you could mention which assembly it is that is in conflict, or do you not know? Generally speaking, this will happen because two projects reference different versions of the same library. Check all your references in every project and look for any two that are the same library but different versions. It might also be because the application project targets a different version of .NET than a library project.

Comment: What computer system for the last 50 years when compiling software did not result in a folder with .dll's and libraries code required to run that code? How could that be a surprise anymore then realizing that computers need electricity to run? That concept of .dll's and compiled software required into a folder for the application to run? I not aware of any computer system that does not work that way for 50+ years. As noted, it looks like some of those libraries have more then one copy. If these are your library's of code, then I would re-compile those assemblies to 4.5.2 also.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, it is the 11 other projects which each create a DLL. I expect those projects to create DLLs, but don't understand why the build then has a problem with the DLLs created.  For example, one of the projects is named PJATools. It's a library assembly, so it will create a PJATools.dll. It complains about that DLL, however can only find 1 instance of it in the solution.

Comment: Does the application project reference the other projects or does it reference the DLLs they create at some specific location? If it's the latter, you should change it to the former. Do any of the library projects reference any other of the libraries? Make sure that they are all project references too. Are all the projects targeting the same version of .NET? Are there any other libraries that are referenced by multiple projects that may be mismatched?